React Hook Form not Showing Validation Error for Specific Field
I'm encountering an issue with React Hook Form where validation errors for a specific field (blog_cat) are not showing up as expected. I've set up the form validation using the zod library, and all other fields are working correctly. However, despite ensuring that the field is registered correctly and that the validation rules are properly defined, I'm not seeing the validation error message when the field is left empty.


const schema = z.object({
        blog: z.string({ required_error: "Please enter a blog content, it cannot be empty!!!" }).min(50, { message: "Blog content should be atleast minimum 50 characters" }),
        title: z.string().min(5, { message: "Title should be atleast minimum 5 characters" }),
        reading_time: z.string({ required_error: "Reading Time required" }),
        featured_image: z
            .any()
            // To not allow empty files
            .refine((files) => files?.length >= 1, { message: 'Image is required.' })
            // To not allow files other than images
            .refine((files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type), {
                message: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp files are accepted.',
            })
            // To not allow files larger than 5MB
            .refine((files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, {
                message: `Max file size is 5MB.`,
            }),
        blog_cat: z.string({required_error : "Please select one of blog cateogry"}).min(6, {message :  "Please select one of blog cateogry"} ),
        tags: z.array(z.string()).min(1, { message: "At least one tag is required" }),


    })

<div>
                            <label htmlFor="countries" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">Blog Category</label>
                            <select id="countries"
                                {...register('blog_cat')}
                                value={something.blog_cat}
                                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => setSomething({ ...something, blog_cat: e.target.value })}
                                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-black dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                                <option selected>Choose a Blog Type</option>
                                <option value="Food Blogs">Food Blogs</option>
                                <option value="Technology Blog">Technology Blog</option>
                                <option value="Travel Blogs">Travel Blogs</option>
                                <option value="Personal Blogs/LifeStyle Blog">Personal Blogs/LifeStyle Blog</option>
                                <option value="Business Blog">Business Blog</option>
                            </select>
                            {errors.blog_cat && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.blog_cat?.message?.toString()}</p>}
                        </div>

 <div>
                            <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">Tags</label>
                      
                            <ReactTags
                                classNames={{
                                    tags: "flex flex-wrap",
                                    tag: "bg-gray-50 mb-5 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 p-2.5 mb-2 mr-2",
                                    remove: "text-gray-400 ml-2",
                                    suggestions: "bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-md z-10 absolute",
                                    activeSuggestion: "cursor-pointer bg-gray-100",
                                }}
                                {...register("tags")}
                                tags={something.tags}
                                handleAddition={HandleAddition}
                                handleDelete={HandleDeletion}
                                inputFieldPosition="bottom"
                                autocomplete
                                inputFieldClass="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-black dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                            />
                            {errors.tags && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.tags?.message}</p>}





                        </div>



More like drop down to select the items it non items are selected it should throw an error but no errors are shown and for tags it's just showing "required" error instead the custom error

If I'm not mistaken, it's incorrect to use selected attr on select options with React Hook Form. The first option should simply have an empty value, without the selected attr. And something.blog_cat should be initialized as "" | undefined.
